# Browser, behind Squid, can't establish connection to socket.io websockets transport

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io, squid

My problem is simple to explain but not so simple to fix I think since I haven't found a solution yet.

I'm developing an API. The backend is developed using NodeJs and Socket.Io. Everything works perfect but the issue arises when I'm on a net that's behind a firewall, Squid in this case. It is the browser who is behind the firewall not the server (NodeJs).

The thing is that I get this error:

**WebSocket connection to 'ws://mydomain.com/socket.io/1/websocket/vN8hWt_EjV0Z5P5-GwrW' failed: Unexpected response code: 502 (socket.io.js:2)**

and I don't know how to the browser can skip Squid.

Comment: Is Squid WebSocket aware? If not (and in general), use `wss` and terminate the TLS at the backend Node, not Squid.

Comment: No I don't think so. Nevertheless, I spoke to the guy in charge and he opened port 80 for incomming requests and that was it. Thanks anyway!